# Is it possible to make applications a drupal modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework, drupal, content-management-system

I'm gonna make a website with many applications running inside.
Do you think that it's possible to use Drupal as a CMS and then change my applications into drupal Module?
Or is it more flexible to create your own CMS? For the moment i'm developing with zend framework. Is it better for me to stick with it or do you think it's a gain of time to switch to drupal and develop the modules that i need?

I also heard that Drupal has some problem about speed...

Many thanks in advance for your answers.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has got a very good abstraction interface that you can build applications that sit alongside it and adhere to its protocol.

CiviCRM has been built so it can work with Drupal, Joomla (and other CMS'es) by sitting alongside them and implementing the specific protocol of each CMS. This works out quite nicely for us. You can also choose to either use drupal as a library or not, i.e. you have the option of using Zend as your PHP library

lobo

Answer (score 2):

I've ported/imported several application into Drupal.  There are several modules out there now that do this: CiviCRM, simplesamlphp_auth (not on drupal.org), FCK/CKeditor.  The common approach of these modules is that they typically treat the external application like a library, and this is what I've done for my internal modules.  Drupal gives enough flexibility to make this work, though some hacking may be required.

Comment: do you mean "hacking the core of drupal"? So for each module you have to hack a bit of drupal? isn't it better to create your own CMS instead of having to force a CMS to work the way you want it to?

Comment: No, hacking in the sense that you may have to use some "inelegant" methods to make it work.